# Is there a place to get/view pro replays on Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

It would be cool if you could look at replays of people on the ladder, but until that happens can you download other people's replays? Is there a repository or something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TeamLiquid has a big [SC2 Replaythread](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=134972), also a good place to talk about reps.

If you want to study replays and analyse them I suggest the youtube channels of [hdstarcraft](http://www.youtube.com/hdstarcraft) and [huskystarcraft](http://www.youtube.com/huskystarcraft). They upload commented games with a bit of analyzing and also provide some tutorials.
For a deeper game analysis I can recommend [Day[9] Daily episodes](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=104154).

Good places to find pure Replays to download are [SC2 Replay section of nibbits.com](http://sc2.nibbits.com/replays/) and [sc2rc.com](http://www.sc2rc.com/index.php/replay/browse)

The sites metioned by Michael are also great resources ;)

Answer (score 2):

[GameReplays.org has a Starcraft II section](http://www.gamereplays.org/starcraft2/replays.php?game=33). I think anyone can join and add their own replays so it's not focused on "pro replays", but I'm sure there are some very good ones on there. They have an "expert replays" section, but there's nothing in it yet.

There's also [SCReplays.com](http://screplays.com/) that has the same "host your replay" philosophy.

I think you'll have to wait a while before one definitive source comes for expert replays, since the game is so new. I doubt anyone went to the trouble for the beta.

Answer (score 0):

I can add only http://sc2play.pro, which has both Replays and Video on Demand.