# What are good sources for Starcraft 2 replays?

Tags: starcraft-2

There are so many replay sites, and so many of them are useless.
So many replays and replay packs are on megaupload-like sites and submitted only to some forums.

What is the best way of searching for replays of good players?

Edit:
1. If you want to post a replay site, make one post per site.
2. Avoid duplicates, upvote instead.

Comment: Teamliquid's replay thread is just to "diluted" to be useful.

Comment: Community Wiki? List of sites? Or "Best" and it's subjective?

Comment: @McKay I changed the title.  I'm a little torn on this, because while it is a decent question, it is another "list" question.

Comment: it's not asking for a solution to a problem.

Comment: It is a very frequently asked question.
This page will be valuable for a lot of people.
We shouldn't so strict.

Comment: @Lew looking back at this question, I almost feel it would be better if it asked for specific replays instead of just a list of websites.  A list of websites is nothing more than a vetted google query, but a list of good replays would be better content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4041/is-there-a-place-to-get-view-pro-replays-on-starcraft-2

Answer (score 3):

Many of the top players have their games posted on [GosuGamers](http://www.gosugamers.net/starcraft2/replays/). Further, the games are rated by the community, so you will know which games will be the most entertaining or informative.

Answer (score 3):

[Sc2Replayed](http://www.sc2replayed.com/) is a new site that is capable of extracting a lot of interesting informations ("DNA", builds, upgrades) from replays.

It also has extremely high uploads/day rate.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite youtube channels are below in no particular order.

[day9tv](http://www.youtube.com/day9tv),
[AskJoshy](http://www.youtube.com/AskJoshy),
[HDstarcraft](http://www.youtube.com/HDstarcraft),
[HuskyStarcraft](http://www.youtube.com/HuskyStarcraft),
[moletrap](http://www.youtube.com/moletrap)

Comment: Keep in mind that watching a replay over YouTube is not the same as watching an actual replay on SC2. With SC2 replays you can keep close tabs on things like build order because you have full control over what you want to be watching at all times.

Comment: Exactly. That's why I asked for replays, not vods.
But FPVODs might be even better than replays.

Answer (score 1):

check out [replayladder.com](http://www.replayladder.com)

Answer (score 1):

[GameReplays](http://www.gamereplays.org/starcraft2/) has lots of actual replays posted. Replays of the week tend to be higher caliber ones, although you can find plenty of others there as well.

Answer (score 1):

http://teamliquid.net/replay/

Answer (score 1):

[gomtv.net](http://www.gomtv.net/) is also very good.

They have a korean version too. The comments are by Tasteless and Arthosis. They provide good analysis of the games. Each season has about 5 hours of free replays.

Answer (score -1):

www.elitegrounds.net has a lot of good replays

Comment: welcome to the arqade! 

I am upvoting because the OP has directly asked for "minimalistic" information, however, that is a general fault on the OPs side.