# Where to get high level starcraft 2 replays?

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are good sources for Starcraft 2 replays?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4685/what-are-good-sources-for-starcraft-2-replays)

There are some pretty good replays out there with audio commentary. Like Starcraft HD and (same guys) more recently www.starcraftarena.net.

I was wondering where those guys get the replays of the top players? Is there a secret database somewhere? The reason for this is that I do understand the strategies, but sometimes the commentator doesn't look where I'd like him to look so watching the replay by myself could me more informative.

Answer (score 2):

Here a list of replay sites for SC2. They all have more or less the same replays.

- [gamereplays](http://gamereplays.org/starcraft2/replays.php?game=33)
- [sc2replayed](http://sc2replayed.com/)
- [gosugamers](http://gosugamers.net/starcraft2/replays/)
- [sc2.replays.net](http://sc2.replays.net/replay/replaylist.aspx) (korean)

Comment: @Jon fixed your links

Comment: pretty sure replays.net is chinese, not korean.

Comment: sc2replayed redirects to curse.com